# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/telephony/data/ApnSetting$Builder;

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a mobile application to add APN(Access Point Network) into mobile application. Then I used `ApnSetting.Builder()` according to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting.Builder.html)

I implemented it as following in `MainActivity` class:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.data.ApnSetting;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create an MMS proxy address with a hostname. A network might not be
        // available, so supply a dummy (0.0.0.0) IPv4 address to avoid DNS lookup.
        String host = "mms.example.com";
        byte[] ipAddress = new byte[4];
        InetAddress mmsProxy;
        try {
            mmsProxy = InetAddress.getByAddress(host, ipAddress);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        ApnSetting apn = new ApnSetting.Builder()
            .setApnTypeBitmask(ApnSetting.TYPE_DEFAULT | ApnSetting.TYPE_MMS)
            .setApnName("apn.example.com")
            .setEntryName("Example Carrier APN")
            .setMmsc(Uri.parse("http://mms.example.com:8002"))
            .setMmsProxyAddress(mmsProxy)
            .setMmsProxyPort(8799)
            .build();
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        devicePolicyManager.addOverrideApn(name, apn);
    }
}
```

But it is showing the following error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4314
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/telephony/data/ApnSetting$Builder;
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.telephony.data.ApnSetting$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.telephony.data.ApnSetting$Builder
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

So what should I do for that?

Comment: `ApnSetting.Builder()` added in API level 28. To call `ApnSetting.Builder()` you required **API level >= 28**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`ApnSetting`** has added in **API level 28** means below **API level 28** don't have that method `ApnSetting.Builder()`. That's why it's not working and causing `ClassNotFoundException` in Android API level < 28.

**Option - 1:**

> If you really want to use this **API** and don't need to support **older
>   devices** just set the **minSdkVersion** to **28** in your build.gradle or
>   AndroidManifest.xml

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        minSdkVersion 28 // this is important 
        targetSdkVersion 29

        ...
    }
}
```

**Option - 2:**

> If your code is **deliberately** accessing newer APIs, and you have
>   ensured (e.g. with conditional execution) that this code will only
>   ever be called on a supported platform, then you can annotate your
>   class or method with the **@TargetApi** annotation specifying the local
>   minimum SDK to apply, such as **@TargetApi(28)**, such that this check
>   considers 28 rather than your manifest file's minimum SDK as the
>   required **API level**.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {

    ...

    ApnSetting apn = new ApnSetting.Builder()
        ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried. but actually I need to create this mobile application for the below versions also. (Lollipop, Nougat) not only for the android 9. So What is the alternative way for the `ApnSetting.Builder()`?. How should I search in google for that?

Comment: That should be a different question. Isn't it? Keep this as it is as it's a reference for future user. Hope you understand

Comment: Yes, I understood.